# loading massively large static data in SwiftUI/Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

What I'm trying to accomplish is loading a large dataset of values into swiftUI so i can have them as static information available inside the app. I have an excel file that has over 4000 rows with about 20 economic data about every country. And I'm planning on adding an additional 10,000 rows in the near future. I've managed to convert the entire data into tuple format and this is what I currently have:

```
var countryInfo:[(economicIndicator:String, country:String, year:String, dataValue:String)] = [ //100th line of code
    (economicIndicator: "GDP", country: "Afghanistan", year: "2018", dataValue: "$19.36 billion"),
    (economicIndicator: "Inflation.", country: "Afghanistan", year: "2019", dataValue: "2.3%"),
    (economicIndicator: "CPI", country: "Afghanistan", year: "2017", dataValue: "$1.014 billion")
    ...
    (economicIndicator: "GDP", country: "Afghanistan" , year: "2018" , dataValue:  "$31 billion"),
    (economicIndicator: "Inflation.", country: "Afghanistan", year: "2019", dataValue: "255.29%"),
    (economicIndicator: "CPI", country:"Afghanistan", year: "2017", dataValue: "$7 billion") //4117th line of code
]
```

and the following is a mini SwiftUI view:

```
struct CountryStatistics: View {
    @State private var currentCountry = countryInfo.filter { $0.country == "Zimbabwe" }
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("country: \(self.currentCountry[0].country)")
            HStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    ForEach(0..<currentCountry.count){ i in
                        Text("\(currentCountry[i].economicIndicator)")
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
                    }
                }.padding()
                VStack(alignment:.leading){
                    ForEach(0..<currentCountry.count){ i in
                        Text("\(currentCountry[i].dataValue)")
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
                    }
                }.padding()
            }
            HStack{
                Button("Change to Afghanistan"){
                    self.currentCountry = countryInfo.filter { $0.country == "Afghanistan" }
                }
                Button("Change to Zimbabwe"){
                    self.currentCountry = countryInfo.filter { $0.country == "Zimbabwe" }
                }
            }
        }.animation(.easeIn)
    }}
```

As you can imagine, xCode slows down heavily trying to run with a tuple that has 4000+ values and my app simply just won't run even after letting xCode attempt to run for 30 mins. There is no errors and it works fine if I test it with a tuple of about 20 rows. I assume this is because this is not how tuples are supposed to be used and that's why xCode isn't running. I wanted to try my best to build my first app and publish to the appStore so I thought tuples might be the easiest route, but I'm seeing this might not be possible.

Is there a more efficient way of loading all that data into my app, or anyway to make swift actually run the code? I don't want to rely on an online API since I want the data to be available for users offline.

Edit- I've also attempted to try doing through JSON but things just wouldn't work and I think it might be because of the custom format of the json, since i made it by hand. This is what I had but still had issues after getting a json decoder function, so I stayed with tuples:

```
[{
    "country":"Afghanistan",
    "facts":[{
        "GDP":"$19.36 billion",
        "Inflation":"2.3%",
        "CPI":"$1.014 billion",
    }]
},{
    "country":"Zimbabwe",
    "facts":[{
        "GDP":"$31 billion",
        "Inflation":"255.29%",
        "CPI":"$7 billion",
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Load & parse file in background thread and show in UI by small blocks. You do everything on main thread that is why all so slow.

Comment: I've tried to add an empty array as a state variable and load it with the code below, but still having problems with swift running it
`
.onAppear(){
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                currentCountry = allCountry //allCountry is a var ouside the view as an array with all the tuples of country informations
               }
                }
`
Is that what you had in mind, any way to improve it?